# Perl's Mechanize and save_content()

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm trying to go paperless with all my utility bills, and that means downloading the statements from Suddenlink instead of stuffing the paper ones into a filing cabinet.

I've used WWW::Mechanize before and I've liked it (Why did I try to do this stuff in LWP for so long?), and so I've went ahead and gotten a workable script ready. I can log in, navigate to the page that lists the pdf links, and loop through those.

I do the following:

```
my $pdf = $mech->clone();

for my $link ($mech->find_all_links(url_regex => qr/viewstatement\.html/)) {

  [removed for brevity]

  unless (-f "Suddenlink/$year/$date.pdf") {

    $pdf->get($link->url);
    $pdf->save_content("Suddenlink/$year/$date.pdf", binary => 1);
```

When I compare one of these files with the same downloaded via Chrome, it's apparent what the problem is. Both files are identical on up to about 8-24 kbytes (it varies), but the Chrome pdf will be complete, and the perl-script pdf will be truncated.

It's late, and there's nothing obviously wrong with the code. Google is turning up a few problems with save_content(), but not anything like what I'm getting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would delete this, but having discovered the issue I want to remind everyone else... set $mech->agent_alias() to something. If I comment this out, it fails again, uncomment and it works. They're doing a connection reset whenever they see a weird user agent string. F**k Suddenlink.

Comment: I made a community wiki answer that you can select as solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...[S]et `$mech->agent_alias()` to something. [Suddenlink is] doing a connection reset whenever they see a weird user agent string.
>   –  John O 18 hours ago